# How to return to main menu with many menu inside?

Tags: c#

If I have a lot of menu on my program how do i return on my main menu without using any loop.
Assume that I need "Y" for return,"N" for end program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {int choice;
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Rent");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Return");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
        choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (choice!= 3)
        {
         if  (choice ==1)
          {...
           //when complete all thing in choice 1
           Console.WriteLine("Do you want to start over?(Y=Yes,N=No)");
           // in this part i need to go back to main menu with "Y" input and close program with "N"input
          }
         if (choice ==2)
          {...
           //when complete all thing in choice 2
          Console.WriteLine("Do you want to start over?(Y=Yes,N=No)");
           // doing like choice 1 }
```

Comment: I can't make any sense of what you are asking. Do you have code, a picture, or something else to clarify?

Comment: This is very unclear. You at least need to provide some pseudo code as to  how this program should flow.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question,I'm already update my question. @thewisegod

Comment: Sorry,I very new to programming and this web.@mmking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it differently, but based on your code, this will get you what you want.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)   
  {
      int choice = 0;
      while (choice != 3)
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
           Console.WriteLine("Rent=1");
           Console.WriteLine("Return=2");
           Console.WriteLine("Exit=3)");
           choice = GetUserChoice("What is your choice?", choice);
           if (choice == 1)
           {
              //when complete all thing in choice 1
              choice = GetUserChoice("Do you want to start over?(Y=1,N=3)", choice);
           }
           else if(choice == 2)
           {
               //when complete all thing in choice 2
               choice = GetUserChoice("Do you want to start over?(Y=1,N=3)", choice);
           }
       }
   }

   private static int GetUserChoice(string question, int choice)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(question);
       return  Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   }
```

Notice inside the choices when it asks about starting over, I would have the user enter 1 for Y(yes) and 3 for N(no).

Comment: Should I need to declare GetUserChoice into int. @thewisegod

Comment: In this scenario, yes. Because that is what you were expecting to read and parse from the user. If you were taking in strings and not parsing into an int, your return type would be string.